# How To Add Spacing In Front of the Font

Tags: swiftui

[image]

How can I add the space to all the image icon and the title?  I want to make it look like this

---

[image]

---

and still keep the gray background color. With padding, I got this

---

[image]

```
struct SampleView : View {
    var myData: myDataItem?
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:10) {
        Text("sample message").font(.system(size: 12)).fontWeight(.medium)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 24, maxHeight: 24, alignment: .topLeading)
            .background(Color("lightGray"))
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBasemyData, spacing: 5) {
            Image("info")
            Text("Discount").fontWeight(.regular)
            Spacer()
            Text("$\(String(format: "%.2f", (self.myData?.discount)!)) ").fontWeight(.regular)
        }
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBasemyData, spacing: 5) {
            Image("info")
            Text("sample message”").fontWeight(.regular)
            Spacer()
            Text("$\(String(format: "%.2f", (self.myData?.planPaid)!)) ").fontWeight(.regular)
        }
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBasemyData, spacing: 5) {
            Image("info")
            Text("sample message1").fontWeight(.regular)
            Spacer()
            Text("$\(String(format: "%.2f", (self.myData?.sampledata)!)) ").fontWeight(.regular)
        }
    }.font(.system(size: 16))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted padding, like

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:10) {
       // ... content here
    }.font(.system(size: 16))
    .padding(.horizontal)                    // << here !!
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. The main goal is keeping the background color all the way across the screen.Sorry, this solution will move the gray background along with the padding.

Comment: Then just put internal HStack/s into another internal VStack with padding.

Comment: seems like the frame won't overlay the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the sub-content in another view (VStack) and then add padding to that stack only.

```
struct SampleView : View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:10) {
            Text("sample message").font(.system(size: 12)).fontWeight(.medium)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 24, maxHeight: 24, alignment: .topLeading)
                .background(Color.gray)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:10) { // <-- NEW!
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                    Image(systemName: "info").background(Color.blue)
                    Text("Discount").fontWeight(.regular)
                    Spacer()
                }
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                    Image(systemName: "info").background(Color.blue)
                    Text("sample message”").fontWeight(.regular)
                    Spacer()
                }
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                    Image(systemName: "info").background(Color.blue)
                    Text("sample message1").fontWeight(.regular)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal) // <-- HERE
            
        }.font(.system(size: 16))
    }
}
```